# Parse for iOS mobile app why extend query does not work using javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am new to both swift and javascript.
I have my IOS application in swift and used parse for my database server. I have a class named Photostable10 over parse server and trying to retrieve the data from it it returns nothing and results length is 0, please help
below is my cloud code  and I use Curl command to run it( curl -X POST  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxxxxx"  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxxxxxxxx"  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d "{}"  https://api.parse.com/1/functions/DeleteData )

```
Parse.Cloud.define("DeleteData", function(request, response) {

ListItem = Parse.Object.extend("Photostable10");


query = new Parse.Query(ListItem);


query.equalTo('code', 2500)
query.limit = 10;
query.descending('createdAt');


query.find({
  success: function(results) {
   response.success("Results count is  " + results.length);
    //Success callback
  },
  error: function(error) {
response.error(err);
    //Error Callback
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing "var" declaration.

Try:

```
var ListItem = Parse.Object.extend("Photostable10");
```

and

```
var query = new Parse.Query(ListItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing:

-"var" declaration for the query

-';' after "query.equalTo('code', 2500)"

-you dont close your first '{'.

Try this :

```
Parse.Cloud.define("DeleteData", function(request, response) {

    var query = new Parse.Query("ListItem"); 
    query.equalTo('code', 2500);
    query.limit = 10;
    query.descending('createdAt');

    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            response.success("Results count is  " + results.length);
            //Success callback
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error(error);
            //Error Callback
        }
    });
});
```